# Magento 2.2 Ajax not working on second time in category page

Tags: magento2, url, ajax, pagination, category-page

My site was working fine, suddenly the ajax on category pages is not working on second time. On first time it works fine, whether it is pagination or layered navigation but on second time it doesn't work. I found out that the url's are generating in-correct the second time.
On first click it is "headsets?p=2", while after the page ajax loads, it is "headsets&p=2?p=3"
and same case is for layered navigation, doesn't work on second time.

Also the code and database are working on local machine and stage site, I run deployment with git/Jenkins, so code and database are same on all platforms, and the issue is only on live site.

page-ul: https://www.thetelecomshop.com/au/headsets

Comment: I face same issue in my site, have u get any solution for this ?

Comment: Yes it was resolved! It was some extension issue, that was removing ?ajax=1 from URLs'.
I changed:
app/code/Sm/ShopBy/Plugin/Category/View.php 
commented out this line:
$requestUri = preg_replace('/(\?|&)ajax=1/', '', $requestUri);

Comment: Thanks for replying @Arsalan Ul Haq :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was resolved!

It was some extension issue, that was removing `?ajax=1` from URLs'.

I changed: `app/code/Sm/ShopBy/Plugin/Category/View.php`

commented out this line:

```
$requestUri = preg_replace('/(\?|&)ajax=1/', '', $requestUri)
```

Comment: For me it doesn't work after a day or two. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302349/ajax-pagination-issue-with-varnish

Comment: Did you checked removing the "&shopbyAjax=1" from the url and try hitting the url then? Can't comment on your post because of low reputation profile.
Also try changing this line
"window.location = (this.url.indexOf('shopbyAjax') == -1) ? this.url : url;"
to
"window.location = (this.url.indexOf('shopbyAjax') == -1) ? url : url;"

Comment: dude, saved the day.

Comment: @Flakerim Did it worked fine?

Comment: Just Disable whole SM_SHOPBY.