# Ajax pagination issue with Varnish

Tags: magento2, varnish, redis, amasty

Store has Magento 2.3.3 with Varnish 6, Redis 5 and Amasty Layered navigation enabled for filtering and pagination ajax calls.
After setting up above configuration, navigation through category pages. Previous and next page clicks via Ajax calls works fine.
Next day or after 24 hours or so, no response after clicking previous and next category pages. Issue disappears after clearing page cache.

Do I need to modify VCL to either exclude Ajax requests or cache ajax requests? While click next page or previous page I see XHR requests with `&shopbyAjax=1` appended to paginated URL. Example https://www.example.com/salwar-kameez?p=8&shopbyAjax=1

Answer (score 0):

In Redis environment - Get Method is always comes from cache when it generated so based on that below is the  solution.

Please change Ajax method to POST or you can use timestamp parameter pass with GET method like &shopbyAjax=1&_=1580169600

Comment: Is there are workaround without touching the code? I mean through configuration files.

Comment: No configuration files here. You need to check your ajax call and above solution you can implement it

Comment: It is Amasty layered navigation extension which is making these Ajax calls. Can you advise the file location and modification required?

Comment: can you provide project link? so i am better way communicate with you

Comment: https://improved-layered-navigation-m2.magento-demo.amasty.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Amasty_Shopby/js/amShopbyAjax.js

Comment: You can add POST method that js file - As below mentioned

$.ajax({
 url: clearUrl,
 
replace to 

$.ajax({
 url: clearUrl,
 type: "POST",

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but I am thinking why not set cache false which is in the same line you have suggested. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Also will the issue disappear if I disable Redis?

Comment: Type: Post solution doesn't seem to work. Ajax pagination breaks when navigating in reverse like from page 5 to page 4. The second solution is working which is timestamp parameter. But in this case the cache is not used. Can this issue be bypassed if Redis is disabled completely.

Comment: Did you checked removing the "&shopbyAjax=1" from the url and try hitting the url then? 
Also try changing this line "window.location = (this.url.indexOf('shopbyAjax') == -1) ? this.url : url;" to "window.location = (this.url.indexOf('shopbyAjax') == -1) ? url : url;"

Comment: I tried that fix, but it doesn't work on magento 2.4.3-p1 and amasty shopby version 2.17.2. Any more ideas about this issue ?

Comment: I'm facing the same type of issues. These didn't come up until we enabled Varnish and now we're having lots of ajax issues with Magento. Unfortunately, the "post" solution doesn't work and neither does the "timestamp" method. Still looking for other possible solutions.